# How to correctly markup sub-navigation with HTML5 / Aria?

Tags: html, navigation, semantic-markup, wai-aria

I have some HTML which essentially looks like the following:

```
<section>
    <h1>Release Notes for 1.0</h1>

    <aside class="versions">
        <h1>Other Versions</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="?ver=3.0">3.0</a></li>
            <li><a href="?ver=2.0">2.0</a></li>
            <li class="active">1.0</li>
        </ul>
    </aside>

    <p>Information...</p>
</section>
```

I may be mistaken, but it doesn't seem appropriate to use the `<nav>` element for this. It also doesn't seem appropriate to use `role="contentinfo"`.

What is the proper way to markup the list of versions to avoid incorrectly being associated with the section currently headed "Release Notes for 1.0"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following structure would be more appropriate if it really is *the* (sub)menu to navigate the different release notes:

```
<div> <!-- maybe use 'section' instead; depends on whole page structure -->
  <nav>
    <h1>All release notes</h1>
    <ul><!-- … --></ul>
  </nav>
  <article> <!-- instead of 'section' -->
    <h1>Release Notes for 1.0</h1>
    <p><!-- … --></p>
  </article>
</div>
```

Your example seems to be appropriate when the links are meant like "You might also be interested in …", but don’t serve as the primary method to navigate to other release notes documents. But in this case, I wouldn’t include the current document in this list (as you did with `<li class="active">1.0</li>`).

Comment: Since you have used the `article`, would the document-level heading be the name of the company or the name of the product? I was just going to have `<h1>Release Notes for <span class="outline">Product Name</span> 1.0</h1>` where the the outline class is hidden for normal viewing. Thanks :)

Comment: @LeaHayes: (I’m not sure I follow you here.) `article` vs. `section` has no effect on the outline (they work the same, `article` is just a more specific `section`, so to speak). --- In general, for a usual website, the "page heading" should be the site title/logo (i.e., a heading that is a child of `body` and of no other sectioning element). The main content would typically be a sectioning element (e.g., `section` or `article`) that is a child of `body`. This sectioning element contains the "main content heading".